# Is it possible to fit a multivariate regression model where the independent variable is latent?

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, latent-variable

I'm trying to fit a multivariate multiple regression model where the independent variable X is latent but I don't know where to start (I have prior information about the coefficient matrix so I can use some iterative method).

The dependent variable Y is a NxM matrix denoting N observations each from M variables. The latent variable X is a NxP matrix about which we know nothing except the dimensions. In addition to these, we have an initial estimate of the coefficient matrix beta based on prior knowledge. My goal is to find the estimates of latent X and coefficient matrix beta by both using the data matrix Y and the initial coefficient matrix. I thought of constructing an EM algorithm but because of the complexity of multivariate data and latent variable concept, I am totally confused.

Thank you.

Comment: @Andy Amos. Can you please provide some more details. At this point, I can only say -- probably -- hierarchical Bayesian models would work. cf. Gelman and Hill 2007, Cambridge Univ. Press

Comment: @Andy Latent Rasch Regression and PLS1 Regression are also models such as the one you describe. As @suncoolsu said, it would help giving us some further information, esp. about data collection, working hypothesis.

Comment: This sounds like some sort of factor analysis (such as principal component analysis) or maybe a mixture model. I agree that more information would be useful.

Comment: @Andy, latent variable means that it is not directly observable, so without model relating the latent variable to the observable variables it is impossible to estimate anything.

Comment: @suncoolsu @chl @Simon Byrne The dependent variable Y is a NxM matrix denoting N observations each from M variables. The latent variable X is a NxP matrix about which we know nothing except the dimensions. In addition to these, we have an initial estimate of the coefficient matrix beta based on prior knowledge. My goal is to find the estimates of latent X and coefficient matrix beta by both using the data matrix Y and the initial coefficient matrix. I thought of constructing an EM algorithm but because of the complexity of multivariate data and latent variable concept, I am totally confused.

Comment: @Andy. May be a silly question: How did you control the levels of other variables when you were collecting $Y$. Each row in $Y_i$ matrix contains entries $Y_{ij}$ which denote the observed variable corresponding to $j^{th}$ latent variable. One more request: can you please modify your question instead of comments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might we reformulate the question as: 'I have N M-variate observations which I assume to be generated by N corresponding P-variate latent variables i.e. for each case/row M observed numbers are generated by P unobserved numbers.  I have an idea that this mapping is linear with an M x P matrix of coefficients and I want to know what the latent matrix values should be.'?

If that's accurate then you have a multivariate version of the *regression calibration problem*.  Normally one knows X and Y and estimates beta, whereas here one knows Y and beta and estimates / 'backs-out' X.

This is what motivates suncoolsu's question about control - the question is about what distribution assumptions can be made about the marginal distribution of X (if any).  Your EM idea will make sense if you are happy to make distributional assumptions about P(Y | X; beta) and P(X) to apply Bayes theorem (although you won't need to iterate.)

Or maybe that's not the problem you're facing and I just don't understand your description.

Comment: Your reformulation of the question is exactly correct. I think the multivariate calibration is what I'm looking for. However the initial coefficient matrix is not completely correct so I have to find a way to optimize it by an iterative procedure. But before that, thank you very much.